# How fast do very small particles diffuse through still air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, gas, diffusion

I have been trying without success to find the rate at which small particles, on the order of $3\cdot10^{-10}\mathrm{g}$, diffuse in air at room temperature $-$ say 20 to 25 degrees C.

The purpose of this is to determine how fast airflow needs to be in one direction to prevent typical-sized covid19 particles from diffusing in the opposite direction.

If the rate varies dramatically with an order-of-magnitude change in particle mass or over the specified temperature range, I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: Hello! I have provided an edit to your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd be careful taking covid-19 ventilation advice from stack exchange. The latest advice from the UK institute of building services engineers is available for free [here](https://www.cibse.org/knowledge/knowledge-items/detail?id=a0q3Y00000HsaFtQAJ#).

[This paper](https://lyfeair.com/references/Ref%2019%20-%20How%20Far%20Droplets%20Can%20Move.pdf) discusses the motion of droplets, but not specifically covid 19, and [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/effects-of-ventilation-on-the-indoor-spread-of-covid19/CF272DAD7C27DC44F6A9393B0519CAE3) considers the effect of different ventilation schemes on the movement of covid 19 particles.